# How do I get specific error information from GetFile()?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, file, ftp

```
void GetFtpFile(LPCTSTR pszServerName, LPCTSTR pszRemoteFile, LPCTSTR pszLocalFile)
{
   CInternetSession session(_T("My FTP Session"));
   CFtpConnection* pConn = NULL;

   pConn = session.GetFtpConnection(pszServerName);
   //get the file
   if (!pConn->GetFile(pszRemoteFile, pszLocalFile))
   {
      //display an error
   }
   delete pConn;
   session.Close();
}
```

How do I get specific error information from GetFile()?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9627ew2(VS.80).aspx):

> ### Return Value
>
> Nonzero if successful;
>
> > otherwise 0. If the call fails, the
> >     Win32 function GetLastError may be
> >     called to determine the cause of the
> >     error.

[GetLastError()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679360(VS.85).aspx) returns an error code, but you can call [FormatMessage()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679351(VS.85).aspx) to get a human-readable string from the error code.  Here's a utility function that does that for you:

```
std::string formatwinerr(unsigned long errCode)
{
    LPVOID lpMsgBuf;

    FormatMessage(
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | 
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM ,
        0,
        errCode,
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
        (LPTSTR) &lpMsgBuf,
        0, NULL );

    std::string ret((const char*)lpMsgBuf);

    LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: FYI - And for winInet messages a specific module must be specified: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159458/not-sure-why-formatmessage-is-returning-a-blank-string

Answer (score 1):

What about GetLastError()?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9627ew2(VS.80).aspx) it's GetLastError()