# Why is FormatMessage() failing to find a message for WinINet errors?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, wininet, formatmessage

I'm running this to test [FormatMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679351%28VS.85%29.aspx):

```
LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
errCode=12163;

FormatMessage(
    FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | 
    FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM ,
    0,
    errCode,
    0,
    (LPTSTR) &lpMsgBuf,
    0, NULL );
```

However, when it returns `lpMsgBuf` contains NULL...  I was expecting something like [ERROR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385465%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Anything look wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

That's a WinINet error, and so the message associated with it lives in WinINet.dll. You just need to tell FormatMessage() about this in order for it to retrieve the correct message:

```
FormatMessage( 
   // flags:
   FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER  // allocate buffer (free with LocalFree())
   | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS // don't process inserts
   | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_HMODULE,  // retrieve message from specified DLL
   // module to retrieve message text from
   GetModuleHandle(_T("wininet.dll")),
   // error code to look up
   errCode,
   // default language
   0, 
   // address of location to hold pointer to allocated buffer
   (LPTSTR)&lpMsgBuf, 
   // no minimum size
   0, 
   // no arguments
   NULL );
```

This is officially documented on MSDN under the ["Handling Errors" section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383884.aspx) of the WinINet documentation.

Note that you can add the `FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM` flag back in if you want to use this routine for errors that may or may *not* have come from WinINet: with that flag in place, `FormatMessage()` will fall back on the system message table if the error isn't found in wininet.dll. However, [do *not* remove the FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS flag](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2007/11/28/6564257.aspx).

Comment: Working with WinINet taught me a lot of things I didn't particularly ever want to know. :-(