# Map errors returned from WinHttpSendRequest using FormatMessage

Tags: winapi, winhttp, winhttprequest

When invoking `WinHttpSendRequest`, I get an error value using `GetLastError` (e.g `ERROR_WINHTTP_CANNOT_CONNECT`).

But when trying to map the error code to a user friendly error message using `FormatMessage`, no mapping is found.

Is there a way to programmatically map errors returned from WinHTTP methods to a user friendly text without making my own map from error code to text array?

Comment: Did you create your own map?  If so, can I have a copy?  :-)

Comment: No (not yet) I wanted to avoid that and let the system tells me what's the issue behind the error.

Comment: Already [asked and answered here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2159488/2065121).

Comment: @RogerRowland You deserve the bounty even if it wasn't your answer.  I searched SO with a variety of words that I believe should have found that post for me and I didn't stumble on it.  I think you should answer and Mox should accept.

Comment: @JohnFitzpatrick well that's good of you to say but really I think the original answer should get the bounty if anything, all I did was Google (although I *am* pretty good at it) ;-)

Comment: @JohnFitzpatrick I've [discussed on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/192824/218740) and have flagged for moderator attention to try to get your bounty refunded.

Comment: @RogerRowland Obviously better at it than the OP and myself, which is worth 50 points in my opinion.  But I won't force them on you.  I think they will just vanish into the ether...

Comment: @RogerRowland:  There should be a badge for someone who tries to get someone elses bounty refunded.

Comment: @JohnFitzpatrick well, I have got the rosy glowing feeling that comes with "doing the right thing" lol :-) and I see that you've now got your rep back for the bounty. All round win win I think.

Comment: @JohnFitzpatrick ... I saw what you did .... you were determined that I should have it ... very grateful - many thanks!

Comment: @RogerRowland:  That is one possible interpretation.  But easy on the reciprocity or we both get thrown in the penalty box.  I'm having an unusually good reputation day.