# Why WinAPI FormatMessage fails, always returns false

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to get error message from FormatMessage method, but the method always returns false and lpBuffer is null.

I would like to know whhat I am doing wrong?

Thx

```
LPTSTR lpBuffer = NULL;
DWORD dwError = GetLastError();
int nResult = 0;
if (dwError >= 12000 && dwError <= 12174)
{
    logger.info("dwError >= 12000 && dwError <= 12174");
    nResult = FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_HMODULE, GetModuleHandle("wininet.dll"), dwError, 0, lpBuffer, 0, NULL);
}
else
{
    logger.info("in else");
    nResult = FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS, NULL, dwError, MAKELANGID(LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US),lpBuffer, 0, NULL);
}

if (nResult)
{
    logger.critical("Cannot start Drools client [" + m_exe + "] because [" + lpBuffer + "]");
    //wcout << (LPWSTR)lpBuffer << endl;
    LocalFree(lpBuffer);
}
else
{
    logger.critical("Cannot start Drools client [" + m_exe + "] because [ Windows error code : " + boost::lexical_cast<string>(dwError) + " ]");
}
```

Comment: GetLastError() works only for certain API ( the one calling SetLastError() are you sure it is your case?

Comment: MSDN says about FormatMessage: "If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call GetLastError." Did you do that? What is the value returned by GetLastError?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/2159458/395718

Comment: @Dialecticus: This code is from the solution to that question.  Not a dupe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling it wrong. If you pass `FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER` you have to give it the location to store the buffer, so "you must cast the pointer to an LPTSTR (for example, `(LPTSTR)&lpBuffer`)."

I.e:

```
nResult = FormatMessage(
    FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_HMODULE,
    GetModuleHandle("wininet.dll"), 
    dwError, 
    0, 
    (LPTSTR)&lpBuffer, 
    BUFFER_SIZE, 
    NULL
);
```

See the documentation here:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679351(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You must pass `&lpBuffer` to `FormatMessage`, not `lpBuffer`.