# FormatMessage doesn't work

Tags: c, winapi

`FormatMessage()` doesn't work for me no matter what I do. When I have error 12002, `lpBuffer` returns as NULL all the time. This is my code:

```
LPTSTR lpBuffer = NULL;
DWORD dwError = GetLastError();
int nResult = 0;
if (dwError >= 12000 && dwError <= 12174)
{
    nResult = FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_HMODULE, 
        GetModuleHandle("wininet.dll"), dwError, 0, (LPTSTR)&lpBuffer, 0, NULL);
}
else
{
    nResult = FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS, 
        NULL, dwError, MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), (LPTSTR)&lpBuffer, 0, NULL);
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: are `wininet.dll` is loaded already ? what is `GetLastError();` after `FormatMessage` fail ? can assume that `GetModuleHandle("wininet.dll")` fail

Comment: FormatMessage works correctly. It's your code that doesn't work. It's worth being clear about this in question titles.

Comment: Your code works, if `GetModuleHandle("wininet.dll");` doesn't return NULL. If I link against the lib and call InternetOpen it works for me.

Comment: ^^ what @RbMm says.  When faced with a problem like this, your first thought should be to simplify the code by taking out the GetModuleHandle() call and loading into a temp var. on a separate line so that you can easily check its result.   Using multiple system API calls in one statement might look cool, but is actually just difficult to follow and debug:(

Comment: anyway - if `FormatMessage` fail - look and post here `GetLastError()` after this. for not guess.

Comment: Yes, I see the problem is that GetModuleHandle("wininet.dll") returns NULL, but I have no idea why

Comment: if this not typo in name *wininet* - this mean that this dll yet not loaded. if you replace `GetModuleHandle` to `LoadLibrary` will be ok ? you say that call `InternetOpen` - are you not use delay load for wininet.dll ?

Comment: `LoadLibrary("wininet.dll");` works to get the module handle as well.

Comment: Ok. thanks for the answers. I will try LoadLibrary instead

Comment: @RbMm if the error code comes from WinInet to begin with, then obviously the WinInet DLL is loaded. Even the [WinInet documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WinInet/appendix-c-handling-errors) says to use `GetModuleHandle()` when calling `FormatMessage()`.

Comment: Related: [Why is FormatMessage() failing to find a message for WinINet errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159458/)

Comment: @RemyLebeau - in this case unclear how *I see the problem is that `GetModuleHandle("wininet.dll")` returns NULL*

Comment: @RbMm maybe the OP is using WinHTTP instead of WinInet? We don't know, the OP didn't say one way or the other. That would be the only logical reason I can think of for why `GetModuleHandle("wininet.dll")` would fail.

Answer (score 2):

Per WinInet's documentation:

[Handling Errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WinInet/appendix-c-handling-errors)

> To get the error text for an error, call the `FormatMessage` function, passing it an `HMODULE` handle to `Wininet.dll`, which can be obtained using the `GetModuleHandle` function.

Which is in contrast to Microsoft's system documentation:

[System Error Codes (12000-15999)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/debug/system-error-codes--12000-15999-)

> The following list describes system error codes (**errors 12000 to 15999**). They are returned by the `GetLastError` function when many functions fail. **To retrieve the description text for the error in your application, use the `FormatMessage` function with the `FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM` flag**.

That would logically include WinInet error codes in the 12000-12175 range, but in reality it only works for a few select WinInet errors.

Note also that WinInet and WinHTTP share the same 12xxx range of error codes. Error code 12002 is a [WinHTTP error code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winhttp/error-messages):

> ERROR_WINHTTP_TIMEOUT
>
> 12002
>
> This error can be returned as a result of TCP/IP time-out behavior, regardless of time-out values set in Windows HTTP Services.

As well as a [WinInet error code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wininet/wininet-errors):

> ERROR_INTERNET_TIMEOUT
>
> 12002
>
> The request has timed out.

You did not indicate which library you are using. Make sure you are using the correct module when calling `FormatMessage()`. If you get an error from a WinInet function, use `wininet.dll`. If you get an error from a WinHTTP function, use `winhttp.dll`.